# Range of variable in splited form in mathematica

Tags: variable-definitions

How can we put the range of a variable in splited form for a variable?

i.e. p belong to (0, 0.2) && (0.6, 1)

i.e. p belongs to (0, 0.2) and also belongs to (0.6, 1).

Thanking you.

Comment: Lookup `Or`, is this what you want?

Comment: I again clear my doubt, Sir. Please see again.

Comment: Please provide context, plotting, solving, statistics?

Answer (score 1):

This should help you determine if a value belongs in an interval range or group of ranges:

```
f[x_] := IntervalMemberQ[Interval[{0.0, 0.2}, {0.6, 1}], x]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fpt[x_] := 
 If[x > 0 && x < 0.2, 0.3 - x,  
  If[x > 0.6 && x < 1, x - 0.5, Nothing]]
```